# FulllCalendar Jquery, select inside day

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, view, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar and I have to append a "select" to each day in a Month view.

I got the select in each cell but it isn't expanding. If I expand the select programmatically(changing size) it gets expanded but I can't select any option. I can't select any text or element inside a Day Cell too. I think the cells are blocking something so clicks are working correctly

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L17jzba6/
I don't need any event, I use the calendar to pick information for each day and save it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var fechaHoy = new Date();
        var fechaFormateada = $.format.date(fechaHoy, "yyyy-MM-dd");
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: ''
            },
            defaultDate: fechaFormateada,            
            monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio',
                'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
            dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles',
                 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles',
                 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado'],

            viewRender: function(view, element) {
                //var fecha = $.format.date(view.start._d, "dd-MM-yyyy");
                //dia = fecha.substr(0, 2);
                //mes = fecha.substr(3, 2);
                //ano = fecha.substr(6, 4);
                $("td[data-date]:not(.fc-other-month):not(.fc-day-number)").each(function() {
                    var fechaCelda = $(this).attr("data-date");
                    if ($(this).hasClass("fc-past")) {

                        var html = '<select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>';
                        $(this).append(html);
                    }
                    else {
                                      var html = '<select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>';
                        $(this).append(html);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Can you post a jsfiddle or [sofiddle](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: That is all I have. Are the selects expading correctly? I tried inserting a select here http://fullcalendar.io/ and It isn't expanding just like my calendar.

Comment: jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L17jzba6/

Answer (score 0):

guess this is a long time ago but i had the same problem with selects and inputs not working. After long trial and error i got it to work by adding $('#selectid').mousedown(function(event){event.stopPropagation()}) to the select. The fullcalendar binds events to the mousedown which somehow prevent the default browser behaviour for the input elements such as select expanding, input focus etc. by stopping propagation on the mousedown this prevents fullcalendar events from firing There is a bug filed for this but seems not yet fixed 
[google code issue](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=2291&q=select%20click&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars) (im using version 2.3.2 of fullcalendar)